# Return date from saved HTML files *if* date exists

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, attributeerror

I have a set of HTML files that aren't all consistent in formatting, i.e. they come from different places. I need to return a date for when the HTML was updated. I have this python code:

```
from htmldate import find_date
import os
import pandas as pd

master_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir(r'D:\URLtoDateTest'):

    date_for_file = file.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]
    date_for_file = find_date(date_for_file, "%d%m%Y").date()
    df = pd.read_csv(file)

    df['Updated_Date'] = date_for_file 
    master_df = pd.concat([master_df, df])

master_df.to_csv('Url-to-date.csv')
```

But I'm returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Merrie\Desktop\AgaveJan\UrlToDate.py", line 15, in <module>
    date_for_file = find_date(date_for_file, "%d%m%Y").date()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'
```

1. I understand what the `NoneType` error is indicating, but is there a way to identify the date if it exists or will it fail every time it encounters a nonexistent value?
2. Is there a better way to retrieve updated date if available in HTML code?

Comment: If the date isn't in the file name, it will fail every time. You can use the [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) function to get information about a file, such as the last time it was modified ([`st_mtime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_mtime)).

Comment: Wouldn't this give me the date the file was saved/modified locally? I need to scan the contents of the .html file for last modified date within the html code. I.e. my first file has this snippet:  "class="lastUpdatedDate"> October 3, 2019</span>" within the code.

Comment: Yes, it's the local file date. Your code is using some non-standard-library module named `htmldate` to (apparently) find the date in the HTML within the file. I've never heard of that module nor am not aware of any standardized way of including the date of last update in them. Regardless. an alternative and very popular module for parsing the format generally is named beautifulsoup, which might work better for you.

Comment: What is the `file.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]` supposed to accomplish? What format are the file names in? Why do you think passing a portion of a file name to `find_date()` will return the date you want? Your question is very unclear.